# Problem with Ubuntu installation - Black Screen

Tags: boot, drivers, gpu

I have a problem with the installation of Ubuntu on my new desktop. I'm trying to install it from a USB and when I select **try ubuntu** or **install ubuntu**. I get to see the ubuntu loading screen, the main ubuntu page. And then the screen goes black.

Here's a demonstration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQa9WjNIx_A

Here's what I tried:
- Secure boot off then boot without nomodeset and acpi_off or something.

So someone says maybe my GPU isn't supported. Its **MSI r9 390**. Would I need to install drivers for it?

Does anyone please have any clue.

Comment: Refer to the duplicate and read from **3. Black screen**... either GPU cause or UEFI

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/AMD/radeon says that the AMD® Radeon™ R9 390 GPU is supported since Ubuntu 14.04 by default.
If it's not, you should try `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati` 
Maybe you could also try your luck with using https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/AMD/fglrx